# Applying a formula to a whole column: Trouble with arrayformula in sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying to apply a formula to an entire column in sheets that is being populated from a form.  It basically checks students answers vs the correct answers and gives the number correct (which goes to other tabs and does other things).  Currently I've been dragging the formula down, which is an option, but I'd like the formula to automatically be applied through arrayformula, but my current solution just gives me the total count.  Any help would be much appreciated as to where I'm going wrong.

Here is the formula I want applied down (From k22:K)

```
=COUNTIF(F22,$F$3)+Countif(G22,$F$5)+Countif(H22,$F$7)+Countif(I22,$F$9)
```

Here is the failed arrayformula

```
=Arrayformula(COUNTIF(F22:F,$F$3)+Countif(G22:G,$F$5)+Countif(H22:H,$F$7)+Countif(I22:I,$F$9))
```

Comment: Can you please share a sample sheet - because the end result your explaining makes sense but the way it matches up with the data is confusing - so a sample sheet with some dummy data would be easiest

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F3rGNzMiYEuA81B170UW1K0f5m8QhmEehtCVtqZgSWY/edit?usp=sharing  This is the link, I think it may be working, I'll mark it answered once I check it out a little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you don't need countif, the logic is simplier, thy this:

```
=ArrayFormula((F22:F=$F$3)+(G22:G=$F$5)+(H22:H=$F$7)+(I22:I=$F$9))
```

This works bacause `true/false` are converted into `1/0` when you add them.

Comment: This seems to have worked!  Here is the sample sheet in case anyone else comes across this and wants to have a look.  For some reason it isn't counting correctly (you can see the counting in column K (original formula) and column L (Formula without the countif).  I'm going to take a closer look when I get to work, I'm sure thats something simple.  THANK YOU!    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F3rGNzMiYEuA81B170UW1K0f5m8QhmEehtCVtqZgSWY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: it works, correct your formula to this: `=arrayformula((F22:F=$F$3)+(G22:G=$F$5)+(H22:H=$F$7)+(I22:I=$F$9))`. You may also tick the answer as correct. Your axample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Ktx5pe2W0glbseVK2Za1IKb_3DNCYmTYdMo75feCzI/edit?usp=sharing